# Incorrect data in the graph generated by rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool

I am using rrdtool to keep track of time series data for time taken by the end user to login to a web tool.

I am generating the graph it showing incorrect data for MAX and LAST function when the user login time is being plotted at differnce of 1 or 2 days.

following is the rrdtool info

```
rrd_version = "0003"
step = 300
last_update = 1425504642
ds[ds0].type = "GAUGE"
ds[ds0].minimal_heartbeat = 1800
ds[ds0].min = 0.0000000000e+00
ds[ds0].max = NaN
ds[ds0].last_ds = "1.537157"
ds[ds0].value = 6.5783599150e+01
ds[ds0].unknown_sec = 0
rra[0].cf = "AVERAGE"
rra[0].rows = 157680
rra[0].pdp_per_row = 1
rra[0].xff = 0.0000000000e+00
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].value = NaN
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].unknown_datapoints = 0
rra[1].cf = "MAX"
rra[1].rows = 26280
rra[1].pdp_per_row = 12
rra[1].xff = 5.0000000000e-01
rra[1].cdp_prep[0].value = 1.5253171235e+00
rra[1].cdp_prep[0].unknown_datapoints = 0
```

and the graph cmd being used is as follows

```
rrdttol   graph --s 1425315000 
-e 1425487800 
-t "test" 
-w 600  -h 100 
-i  --font DEFAULT:7: 
--vertical-label="Seconds" 
DEF:ln=file_name:ds0:AVERAGE CDEF:login=ln 
COMMENT:"Time Range 03/02/2015 11\:50 - 03/04/2015 11\:50\c" 
COMMENT:"\c" 
COMMENT:"\t" 
AREA:login#00bf00:"Login Times":
STACK PRINT:login:LAST:"Current %3.2lf%sSeconds  " 
GPRINT:login:AVERAGE:"Average %3.2lf%sSeconds   " 
GPRINT:login:MAX:"Max %3.2lf%sSeconds\c"
```

When I dumped the time series data the range is 1-2 sec but graph generated show MAX as 11 sec.

Is there any way in rrdtool to print the value of the period of x-axis.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data from your dump, and the problem graph image?  It would make it easier to identify the apparent error.  The problem may be down to the fact that you have strange RRAs defined -- an AVG with pdp_per_row=1 and a MAX with pdp_per_row=12.  Generally, I would have expected 4 RRAs to be defined -- a MAX and an AVG with pdp_per_row=1 and a MAX and AVG with pdp_per_row=12 .  Note that there is an old issue (fixed in rrdtool 1.5) that means you need to have the pdp_per_row=1 for MAX and AVG even though they are technically the same thing.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you mean by "print the value of the period of x-axis".  Can you rephrase this?

Comment: @SteveShipway I mean to say the scale factor of x and y axis

Comment: The graph function can return the image size in pixels, but not the upper limit of the Y axis.  You should already know the min/max values on the X axis, as these will be the time start/end that you passed when calling the graph function.  So, you can determine the seconds-per-pixel for X from this, but not the scale factor of the Y axis, unless you calculate the limits yourself, and then you specify a rigid upper and lower limit  for the Y axis to prevent autoscaling, of course.